# How to know if I was working during the day or during the night?

Tags: windows, windows-10, monitoring, event-viewer, events

I am working with my computer (Windows 10 Enterprise), sometimes during the day and sometimes during the night. I don't switch off my computer when I go at home.

Is there a way (like in the event viewer) to know when my computer has been actively used? I mean, even when a computer is not used, some entries are entered in the event viewer anyway. I would like to know on what events to filter on "real" user interaction activities.

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Filter the event log for login and logout events, where the security ID is your user.

Comment: Do you know the event IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Windows security log and filter it e.g. using Powershell. I assume it shows the time when the lock screen is unlocked. Depending on lock time out of your system the number of events per day may vary:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='security'; id=4672 }  | where-object  { $_.Message -like '*myusername*' }
```

Tested for an Windows domain account named `myusername` on a system that runs 24/7.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your command looks fine, but only the last events seem to be present, so I have the impression that the event logs get cleaned. Are you are aware of any automatical backups or copies of the event logs and where to find them?

Comment: @Dominique If the configured security event log size is too small then the events are gone. I am not aware of an automated event log export of Windows, may be there are third party tools that do export and clear events.